# R: Can I use percentages instead of counts in a chi-squared & pairwise test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, proportion, count-data

I have count data with a corresponding time and place of each count, but my research question is about proportions. Is it valid to run a chi-squared test on percentages rather than count data? I'm also asking because I don't understand some of the results. For example, "Whipray" in 2016 (value of 43.75000) is "higher than expected value" (Residuals: 4.23 and statistically significant: 0.00027), but the next value (58.33) in 2017 is not higher than expected...just confused why a lower observed value would be significant and a higher observed value than the previous wouldn't be.

```
Contingency table of my data:
library(chisq.posthoc.test)
> table
                   Year
        Zone        2016 2017 2018
          Crocodile    0    8    2
          Rankin       3   17    8
          West         7   31   17
          Whipray      4    4    0
    
    Same data (as average % of total count):
     
> table2
                  Year
        Zone            2016     2017     2018
          Crocodile  0.00000 41.66700 28.57143
          Rankin    27.27273 33.92857 13.23656
          West      23.91304 42.64676 36.01179
          Whipray   43.75000 58.33333  0.00000
    
    > chisq.test(table2)
    
        Pearson's Chi-squared test
    
    data:  table
    X-squared = 76.958, df = 6, p-value = 1.516e-14
    
    > chisq.posthoc.test(table2, method = "bonferroni")
        
          Dimension     Value      2016       2017      2018
        1 Crocodile Residuals -5.727856  1.6457246  4.146400
        2 Crocodile  p values  0.000000  1.0000000  0.000405
        3    Rankin Residuals  2.068596 -0.9662472 -1.050602
        4    Rankin  p values  0.463008  1.0000000  1.000000
        5      West Residuals -1.046354 -2.1617513  3.716144
        6      West  p values  1.000000  0.3676480  0.002427
        7   Whipray Residuals  4.233146  1.5844252 -6.429553
        8   Whipray  p values  0.000277  1.0000000  0.000000
```

Comment: In many threads here on CV it has been pointed out that the answer is "no," because the variability in the numbers depends on the counts and that information is lost when working with proportions.  The meaning of the numbers in Table 2 is unclear, because they have little evident relationship with the counts.  Could you at least explain how `table2` is derived from `table`?

Comment: Ok, well, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the quick answer. 'Table' has the sum of all counts of fish with empty stomachs while 'Table2' are average %'s of fish with empty stomachs per batch out of all fish caught (per batch/catch/haul)

Comment: I re-did the analysis with the sum of counts of fish with empty stomachs (table) and the results still seem odd. Whipray in 2016 and 2017 have the same counts (count of 4), but only Whipray @ 2016 has a higher than expected value (and significant), while the other (2017) is not.

Comment: Whipray 2016 Residuals =  3.0827154, p-value = 0.0246150,   
Whipray 2017 Residuals = -0.5645732, p-value = 1.0000000

Comment: Essentially a duplicate (answers to it are covered by many questions on site) e.g. 1 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/453095/r-same-dataset-different-units-and-then-chi-square-test-no-longer-works e.g. 2 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/398036/is-the-chi-square-test-of-independence-the-best-option-for-3x2-contingency-table/398043#398043 3. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350717/do-i-use-chi-square-test-correctly-for-such-dataset

Comment: Thank you @Glen_b, I have some good answers below.

Comment: @Nate, in general, you can do a chi-squared test with percentages. It's called a goodness-of-fit test. With the R chisq.test function, you just specify p instead of y.

Comment: @Nate they were to establish that the question *should have been closed* not answered; If people have good answers they ought to post them on the most canonical thread rather than in yet another version  of essentially the same question. Pointing out duplicates is step 1 in closing and/or merging. Closure as duplicate (the correct action for this question) has been attained and the top of the post now links to other threads which will help later readers find more good answers (the purpose of the site). At this stage I'll leave it for the mods to consider whether they want to merge it as well.

Comment: Oh ok, no problem. "Closed" seemed like a very ambiguous word choice; I wasn't sure what it meant so to be on the safe side, I clicked no. As long as I can still view these answers again, I don't mind what happens beyond that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the percentages in each Zone within each year. Few or no cases are in Whipray for 2017 or 2018 relative to the total number of cases for those years. In contrast, more than 25% (4/14) are in that Zone for 2016. With a contingency table you need to think about proportions in both directions.

Comment: Aha! Got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have the table of counts
shown below:

```
Cr  = c(0, 8, 2)
Ra  = c(3,17, 8)
We  = c(7,31,17)
Wh  = c(4, 4, 0)
TAB = cbind(Cr,Ra,We,Wh); TAB
     Cr Ra We Wh
[1,]  0  3  7  4
[2,]  8 17 31  4
[3,]  2  8 17  0
```

The low counts (in the first row and first column)
lead to some low expected counts in the chi-squared test, invalidating a chi-squared test of
homogeneity of counts across years.
See the warning message below:

```
chisq.test(TAB)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TAB
X-squared = 12.804, df = 6, p-value = 0.04626

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Specifically, the warning message appears because
some expected counts are smaller than $5.$
Some statisticians are willing to ignore the
warning if only a few expected counts are below $5$ and none are below $3,$ but you clearly
have a problem with low expected counts.

```
chisq.test(TAB)$exp
           Cr        Ra        We       Wh
[1,] 1.386139  3.881188  7.623762 1.108911
[2,] 5.940594 16.633663 32.673267 4.752475
[3,] 2.673267  7.485149 14.702970 2.138614
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TAB) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

As implemented in R, one can simulate a more
accurate P-value for this test as shown below:

```
chisq.test(TAB, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TAB
X-squared = 12.804, df = NA, p-value = 0.03998
```

So, at the 5% significance level you can reject
the null hypothesis that proportions are
homogeneous across years.

You might investigate various scenarios *ad hoc,*
trying to isolate or explain the
the lack of homogeneity, and @EdM (+1) has
mentioned some things to look at. However,
after adjusting significance levels to avoid 'false discovery'
from repeated analyses of the same data,
you may not have enough power for a
successful detailed investigation.

Comment: Another great answer, thank you!